Use a string created in a "If/Else" loop outside of it?
I want to use a If/Else statement in which, the same string value is set and then this created string is used outside of the If/Else loop.
However, I get an error The name '//name of string' does not exist in the current context
        bool hitBell = bellCounter == 0;
    if (hitBell)
    {
        string bell = "You just hit the bell for the first time.";
    }
    else
    {
        //The value "bellCounter" is another int variable not relevant here. It was created outside of the If/Else loop.
                string bell = $"You just hit the bell. But, you already rang it {bellCounter} times before, you are such an impatient person";

    }
    string finalMessage = $"{bell}, let's hope the auditor reacts to it.";
               //Here will be another line of code that increments the "bellCounter" by one.

This is what I tried and it returns the said error. Is this even possible, and if not, what are possible alternatives?

Move the declaration before the if, then just assign a value in the if and else blocks.

Alternatively, you could use a pattern matching switch statement with cases == 0 and default.

Check this: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+variable+scope

Would the following change fix your problem?
bool hitBell = bellCounter == 0;
string bell = "";
if (hitBell)
{
    bell = "You just hit the bell for the first time.";
}
else
{
    //The value "bellCounter" is another int variable not relevant here. It was created outside of the If/Else loop.
    bell = $"You just hit the bell. But, you already rang it {bellCounter} times before, you are such an impatient person";

}
string finalMessage = $"{bell}, let's hope the auditor reacts to it.";
//Here will be another line of code that increments the "bellCounter" by one.


In this case you don't need to initialize the bell variable. The compiler will see that every code path assigns a value before the variable is used.

It works! Thanks!

for such a simple check, you could also use a inline-if during assignment:
var result = (condition)? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse; 

is equivalent to
var result;
if (condition)
   result = valueIfTrue;
else
   result = valueIfFalse;

so, here:
String finalMessage = ((bellCounter == 0)? 
   "You just hit the bell for the first time." : 
   $"You just hit the bell. But, you already rang it {bellCounter} times before, you are such an impatient person"
) + ", let's hope the auditor reacts to it.";

(Not very readable here, just wanted to mention the possibility)
